# SqlDelightTask jetpack compose multiplatform: Execution failed for task ':composeApp:generateCommonMainOnTrackDBInterface'

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform, sqldelight

I have this problem:

SqlDelightTask:

Execution failed for task ':composeApp:generateCommonMainOnTrackDBInterface'.

> A failure occurred while executing app.cash.sqldelight.gradle.SqlDelightTask$GenerateInterfaces
> Generation failed; see the generator error output for details.

[image]

I was, because I had two similar function with the same name, delete this and my problem was solved.

[image]

I was trying to compile my proyect.